# Database present in simulator but not on device build (Copying files from App Bundle to Documents Directory in Swift)

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, swift, simulator

I've got a problem that I'm not able to find an answer to.

I have an app that has a sqlite database (called "myDatabase.sqlite"). In order to get this to work in the simulator build, I found the path for it by using the following code:

```
        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)

    let docsDir = dirPaths[0] as! String

    databasePath = docsDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("myDatabase.sqlite")

    let database = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)
```

This works in the simulator, but I had to physically put the file in that path.

For on-device testing, I'd like this to transfer with the bundle. I have that same database copied into the app bundle (oops, I don't have enough reputation to post images, but it's underneath one of my view controllers in the list of files in the app bundle).

When I run the build on the device, though, I get the following readout from the console:

> Opened database at /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/64ECF088-1AA8-4B9F-AF65-4E36EF10AF9C/Documents/myDatabase.sqlite
>   2015-04-20 11:39:15.991 TestApp[15882:2776428] DB Error: 1 "no such table: cards"
>   2015-04-20 11:39:15.992 TestApp[15882:2776428] DB Query: SELECT * FROM cards
>   2015-04-20 11:39:15.992 TestApp[15882:2776428] DB Path: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/64ECF088-1AA8-4B9F-AF65-4E36EF10AF9C/Documents/myDatabase.sqlite
>   Error: no such table: cards

Does anyone know if I'm doing something obviously wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: The Documents folder is not the same as app bundle.

Comment: If I got that right, you need to add the db to the build target, so it's added to the bundle

Comment: I have it added to the build target (in the copy bundle resources section of build phases). I think that @rmaddy is correct and I need to copy it over into the documents directory. It seems like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534695/how-to-copy-file-from-main-bundle-to-document-folder talks about how to resolve that, but I am having trouble converting from Objective-C to Swift. Does anyone have a quick translation?

Answer (score 2):

So I ended up solving this, but since I haven't seen this anywhere for Swift I'll post for anyone's future use:

There's a class property:

`var databasePath = NSString()`

Then: (I left the debug console output in as comments)

```
func createOrReturnDatabase() -> FMDatabase {

    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)

    let docsDir = dirPaths[0] as! String

    let pathForDB = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath!.stringByAppendingPathComponent("myNewDatabase.sqlite")

    databasePath = docsDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("myNewDatabase.sqlite")

    if !fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(databasePath as String) {
        println("Database not present, so we created one from \(pathForDB)")
        fileManager.copyItemAtPath(pathForDB, toPath: databasePath as String, error: nil)
        println("Copied database to \(databasePath), and a file exists there is: \(fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(databasePath as String))")
        return FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)
    } else {
        println("I returned the database because it exists.")
        return FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check that your database is at the right place on application launch. If it's not, copy it there from your bundle. As @rmaddy noted, the documents folder is not the same as the app bundle.